# что сделать чтобы решить проблему установки VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, setup

Для задания нужен Visual Studio 2013, скачал .exe установщик, запустил, в процессе возникли следующие ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте UAC поставить на самый низкий уровень на время установки, если он включен.